# Linux installs only in Legacy Mode

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

I have got problem with installing Linux and Windows 10 on one laptop. I have installed Windows 10 as the first OS, then Linux. But no matter how I do it, Linux boots only in "Legacy mode". So if I want to run Ubuntu, I have to go to the BIOS, change booting mode to Legacy mode and back again to UEFI if I want Windows 10, which is kinda annoying.

What I have already tried:

- making bootable USB using GPT partitioning
- installing systems on one SSD
- installing Windows on SSD and Linux on HDD (trying to set the boot partition once on HDD second time on the SSD)
- manually installing `grub` and SSD (then nothing booted, I had to reinstall Windows 10, probably I have messed up something)

What may be worth mentioning is that I have converted drives from MBR to GPT in past.

Edit: I have tried Ubuntu 16.04 (32 and 64 bit), 17.10 (64bit) and Mint 17 (both 32 and 64bit).

My bootable USB boots only in UEFI mode, then installing goes smoothly, everything seems great. But after rebooting my computer (still in UEFI) Windows 10 boots automatically, there is no screen to choose OS. When I change booting mode in BIOS to Legacy then Linux boots automatically.

Edit2: I am back. Last time I gave up and worked for a while on live USB but eventually it is impractical and annoying.

This time I literally wiped out my drives - both SSD and HDD. Then removed SSD physically and tried to install Ubuntu - still with the same problem. What I did:

1. Created bootable USB using Rufus2.6 with GPT partitioning for UEFI. OS version: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS 64bit.
2. Created partitions on disk in this order: 100mb unallocated, 650mb EFI Partition (`/dev/sda1`), root partition (`/dev/sda2`), /home partition (`/dev/sda3`), swap.
3. For boot file I have chosen `/dev/sda1` - EFI partition.

and second time the same but for boot file chosen whole disk - /dev/sda (formatting partitions before installation of course).

And strange thing happened during installation - a warning saying about that installation in UEFI mode may damage other already installed in legacy mode OS - as I said, the disk was formatted and the only things what I have got there is just data (like a few GBs of music, films and games).

I does not work anyway nor in Legacy mode nor in UEFI - there is "no bootable devices" info.

Manual installation from live usb is impossible I guess. Tried this for milion times - every time there is a problem. One you solve, another appears.

Why it happens? I remember installing Ubuntu on my PC - it was the easiest and the quickest installation of OS in my life. But now it is so annoying and still does not work...

Thanks for any reply...

Comment: Which linux distro are you installing? Ubuntu? In that case, which version of Ubuntu? is it a 32-bit version or a 64-bit version? Please describe what happens (all details), when you try in UEFI mode.  (Edit your original questions to answer the questions and to describe what happens).

Comment: Thanks for adding details to your original question :-) It is strange, that your bootable USB boots only in UEFI mode, yet the installed system boots only in BIOS (legacy) mode. This is contrary to my experience. Is it possible that you actually boot an Ubuntu system, that was installed earlier? 64-bit Ubuntu (and 64-bit Mint) should work in both UEFI and BIOS mode, and the installed system should boot in the same mode as it was installed. -- It may help if you add details about your computer: Brand name and model and also about the UEFI/BIOS software.

Comment: Back again - I have added a few details.

Comment: May be best to see details, you can run from your Ubuntu live installer or any working install, use ppa version not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info and:
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/ If Lenovo do not install 17.10. the 32 bit installer is BIOS only, so then installing 64 bit in UEFI may see left over bits of 23 bit BIOS install like grub in MBR or bios_grub partition. Many brands need work arounds. What brand/mode & what video card/chip?